# Custom Object creation on Production

Tags: custom-object

I have created the custom object directly on production. is there need of to create this custom object in the sandbox?

Answer (score 2):

> I have created the custom object directly on production.

Firstly, I'd strongly recomment not doing this in the future. Although it may seem harmless, doing any kind of development work in production can cause problems therefore I'd always recommend deploying **everything** from a Sandbox to Production, including Objects.

> is there need of to create this custom object in the sandbox?

The only reason I can think of is if you wish to write Apex against this object, then yes you would have to create it in the Sandbox. However, I'd recommend setting up a Production > Sandbox deployment connection and deploy everything you've made to your sandbox. Going forward, deploy from your Sandbox to Production.

I can't emphasise enough the importance of refraining from doing any development work in production. Even if it's a slight change to a field, by deploying those minor changes to production, if there are any errors, well-written Test Classes can catch these problems before they hit the production environment and stop all kinds of chaos.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine that the new custom object would "appear" automatically in the sandbox when you refresh it. I have never tried this myself though.

Comment: is there any possibilty of issues if i directly create the object on production instead of sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

You should create same object in your sandbox as well to make both environment in sync. It will not create any issue but if in future you want to develop any new functionality around this object you need that object at that time.

Answer (score 0):

The sandbox should be a complete carbon copy of production so once you refresh this object should be there also.

I wouldn't recommend creating anything in production - Dependent on company size; if you are a relatively small company or the only administrator and know your SF organisation inside out then there is no problem as you should be aware of any issues this may cause to validation rules, triggers, workflows etc - If there are more admins / super users / developers etc then do everything primarily in sandbox, get it signed off and then get it into production.

Either way - Have an awesome day :)